# documentation on how to build complex queries for AWS dynamodb for an iOS Application

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to create an application in which a database of users is queried with a relatively complex set of query parameters.  I've found basic documentation on how to query using the aws mobile sdk (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html) but am not sure how to perform more complex operations (i.e. multiple query conditions at the same time).

As an example if I want to query the database for users containing certain values in a list attribute and who fall within a certain lat and lon attribute, how could I do that?

Perhaps this may not be possible with dynamo, but if not then which database type should I use and where would the documentation for forming these multipart queries in iOS be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure range keys for such values and then query using rangeKeyConditionExpression. Something like this:

```
AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression *queryExpression = [AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression new];

queryExpression.indexName = @"Author-Price-index";

queryExpression.hashKeyAttribute = @"Author";
queryExpression.hashKeyValues = @"John Smith";

queryExpression.rangeKeyConditionExpression = @"Price < :val";
queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = @{@":val":@50};
```

This should give you an idea on how to achieve some filtering. You can also use logical operations and conditioning to put multiple filters. Refer: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html

Thanks,
Rohan